# Why is my code not able to split the first string into substrings

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a piece of code that compares two strings. Strings are as follows:

- First String/Array: "ABC;CDE;GBH"
- Second String/Array: "ABC;CDE;GBH;LLL"

I want "LLL" to be in the third cell once the comparison is complete. It just won't give me the result except in the one case where The first string does not have even a single semicolon. In other words, First string is "ABC" (without the semicolon) then it is returning "CDE;GBH;LLL" in the third column.

Code:

```
Function CompareTwo(txt As String, txt2 As String) As String
    Dim a, b
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        For Each a In Split(txt, ";")
            For Each b In Split(txt2, ";")
                If InStr(Trim(a),Trim(b)) <= 0 then .add Trim(b), nothing
            Next b
         Next a
         If .Count > 0 Then CompareTwo = Join(.keys, ";")
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Are you trying to return differences or just what is in the second string but not in the first?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find parts of the second string that are not in the first, try this. You can use Match rather than looping. I think your code would (could) error as you would be trying to add the same key more than once.

```
Function CompareTwo(txt As String, txt2 As String) As String

Dim b

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    For Each b In Split(txt2, ";")
        If IsError(Application.Match(Trim(b), Split(txt, ";"), 0)) Then .Add Trim(b), Nothing
    Next b
    If .Count > 0 Then CompareTwo = Join(.keys, ";")
End With

End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But, it still didn't solve the problem. However, the code I wrote will have input string as unique for every row in excel. For Ex: if a string contains ABC then ABC will not be repeated in the same string again.

Comment: It works for me. If it doesn't work you need to spell out why and what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: So, there are two strings... 1) “Abc;def” 2) “Abc;def;TTY” .... what I need macro to do is... compare each value (which can be split on the basis of semicolon delimiter) of first string in the second string.... in other words, whatever values of second string is not in first string... then add those value to a different cell... in this example: TTY of second string should be displayed in the cell where I apply this formula.

Comment: That's exactly what that code does. See the screenshot.